# undefined in Closures In For Loops

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

```js
var createShoutOuts = function(numbers_list){
  var shoutOuts = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < numbers_list.length; j++) {
    shoutOuts.push(function() {
      var shout_out = 'This is shout out number ' + (j+1);
      console.log(shout_out + '. The number is ' + numbers_list[j]);
    });  
  }
  return shoutOuts;
};

var performShoutOuts = function(user_numbers){
  var readyForShout = createShoutOuts(user_numbers);
  for (var i = 0; i < readyForShout.length; i++) {
    readyForShout[i]();
  };
};

performShoutOuts([2,4,8]);
```

I created the above to teach myself closures. The output is always:

> 'This is shout out number 4. The number is undefined'

I understand that it will always say number 4 because the anonymous functions that are being pushed in to the `shoutOuts` array have a reference to the j variable, not a copy of the value of the j variable. Therefore by the time the anonymous functions are called by `readyForShout[i]();` the for loop has already run and i has the value 4.

What I don't understand is why is it saying undefined? Because it appears to me as though the array that is passed in to `performShoutOuts` should be stored in the closure and should therefore be accessible when `readyForShout[i]();` is executed.

What have I missed?

Comment: You are missing **closures**. You are not at all using the closure concept! Run the snippet in my answer and look at the console. `:)`

Comment: By the time you run the function j = 3 hence the 4 in your result. Also numbers_list[4] IS undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a closure for real:

```js
var createShoutOuts = function(numbers_list){
  var shoutOuts = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < numbers_list.length; j++) {
    shoutOuts.push((function (j) {
      return function () {
        var shout_out = 'This is shout out number ' + (j+1);
        console.log(shout_out + '. The number is ' + numbers_list[j]);
      };
    })(j));
  }
  return shoutOuts;
};

var performShoutOuts = function(user_numbers){
  var readyForShout = createShoutOuts(user_numbers);
  for (var i = 0; i < readyForShout.length; i++) {
    readyForShout[i]();
  };
};

performShoutOuts([2,4,8]);
```

Comment: Thanks @praveen. But why? I have a function inside a function and that inner function is utilising the outer functions variable (in this case the numbers_list parameter that is passed in). I thought that is the concept of a closure - a function within a function that references the outer function's local variables.